# Ruby on Rails - shopping cart - too many orders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, shopping-cart

I was trying to build a shopping cart application in Ruby on Rails. The model is as follows: a user has many deliveries, a delivery has many order_items and products has many order_items.

I was trying to get non-logged-in users to make shopping carts as well and only after they made their cart, the user has to register or log in to submit the order (cart).

As such, I made a helper in the ApplicationController to determine the current-delivery:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
helper_method :current_delivery


  def current_delivery
    if !session[:delivery_id].nil?
      Delivery.find(session[:delivery_id])
    else
      Delivery.new
    end      
  end
end
```

And in the oder_items Controller, I made the create action:

```
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @delivery = current_delivery
    @order_item = @delivery.order_items.new(order_item_params)
    @delivery.save
    session[:delivery_id] = @delivery.id
  end
 ...
end
```

When someone hits the add-to-cart button, the create action of the order_item is fired which:

```
$(".cart-text").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'layouts/cart_text') %>")
```

The problem is that when a user adds an order_item (clicks on add to cart button) to an empty cart, multiple deliveries get created (4-12). How do I get only one new delivery instead of multiple?

Comment: What will happen if user adds item to cart and closes the browser? Do You really want to store all unfinished orders(deliveries)?  I am working on a similar application right now, and I use session to store shopping cart items and save orders to database only on checkout.

Comment: can you show your logs when you click the button?

Comment: @IvanSelivanov That is indeed a far better approach, I was looking for a way to make it behave like that! Thanks : )